# RangeError: locale must contain formatDistance property when using locale variable in Next.js with date-fns

Tags: javascript, next.js, date-fns

I have a website with multiple languages done in Next.js. Next.js provides several methods to get all the locales, here are the following:

```js
{locale} // current locale in use 'es'
{locales} // all the configured locales in an array [ "en", "de", "es", "ja", "ru" ]
{defaultLocale} // if no locale provided, will use en
```

Then in my code, i have this date-fns method to get the distance in days for a given date i get from my createdAt value.

```js
// my import languages
import { es, de, ja, en, ru } from 'date-fns/locale';


<BodyOne>
  This category was funded{' '}
  {formatDistance(new Date(category.createdAt), new Date(), {
    locale: locale,
    })}
</BodyOne>
```

This gives me the following error:

```js
RangeError: locale must contain formatDistance property
```

I don't understand why, this works:

```js
{
  locale: es,
   })}
```

But this one with the variable locale doesn't.

```js
{
  locale: locale,
   })}
```

if I create a new constant, let's say:

```js
const myCurrentLang = es;
```

it works, but if I output:

```js
const myCurrentLang = 'es';
```

I get the error: RangeError: locale must contain formatDistance property

Maybe i need to convert the 'es' value to other type in order to make date-fns work.

Comment: I have read the documentation https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/I18n and I created a new util library called whenHappened that prints the date formated perfectly.

```Javascript
// lib/dateFormat.js
/** @format */

import { formatDistance } from 'date-fns';
import { es, de, ja, en, ru } from 'date-fns/locale';

const locales = { es, de, ja, en, ru };

export default function whenHappened(createdAt, localeId) {
  return formatDistance(new Date(), new Date(createdAt), {
    locale: locales[localeId],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing is formatDistance is waiting for a `namespace` and you're trying to send a `string` as a parameter.
When you declared `const myCurrentLang = es;` it works because es is referring to date-fns/locale's namespace...

Hope it helps